# BIM 360 - Is it possible to find the project id (and additional info) that a resource belongs to if all you have is the urn

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-construction-cloud

We have the urn of a file that we would like to find the id of the project that it belongs to in a clients account as well as the version id. We could always do a recursive search across all of the hubs until we find it, but that would take a long time and several calls. Is there any api that we could use to find that info quickly?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no API supports finding the project id by the given version or item urn. You must store the project id aside urn together.